# Downgrade or install an earlier version of a GitHub library

Tags: c++, libcurl

I have installed [CPR](https://github.com/libcpr/cpr) library in Ubuntu using the following commands:

```
git clone --recursive https://github.com/whoshuu/cpr.git
cd cpr/
mkdir build && cd build
cmake ..
make
sudo make install
```

The version installed is compatible with C++17.
However, I need CPR 1.9.x, which is compatible with C++11. How do I install an earler version of CPR?

Comment: Are you saying IOTA doesn't compile with a newer standard?

Comment: Checkout the wanted version of the library before building it? Like the `1.9.7` tag?

Comment: You can simply checkout a different release from the git repo. E.g. `git switch 1.9.x` for the latest `1.9.x` revision, or `git switch 1.9.7` for a particular release.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat There are too many errors. As the documentation says IOTA uses C++11, I think I should stick with C++11 too.

Comment: Did you confirm that using just IOTA (without CPR) with C++11 does work? Maybe the errors are caused by something else?

Comment: No, I could not. I have been facing too many errors with dependencies for two weeks now.

Comment: @Brian61354270 can you post this as an answer so that I can mark it as an accepted one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can install a different version of the CPR library by checking-out a specific revision in the git repository you cloned.

The CPR library repository includes [branches for tracking minor releases](https://github.com/libcpr/cpr/branches) (e.g. [`1.9.x`](https://github.com/libcpr/cpr/tree/1.9.x), [`1.10.x`](https://github.com/libcpr/cpr/tree/1.10.x)) as well [tags for each specific release](https://github.com/libcpr/cpr/tags) (e.g. [`1.9.7`](https://github.com/libcpr/cpr/releases/tag/1.9.7)).
To install a specific version, simply switch the working tree to the desired revision before executing the build steps.

To install the latest revision of CPR 1.9.x, switch from the `master` branch to the `1.9.x` branch with

```bash
$ git switch 1.9.x
# or
$ git checkout 1.9.x
```

If you want to install a specific tagged version like v1.9.7, you can use

```bash
$ git switch --detach 1.9.7
# or
$ git checkout 1.9.7
```